# Is there any multiplicative linear functional on B(H)?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

If A is a Banach algebra, we say that $\Phi: A \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a multiplicative linear functional if $\Phi$ is nontrivial, linear and $\Phi(xy)=\Phi(x)\Phi(y)$.

It is easy to see that there is no multiplicative linear functional on $M_n(\mathbb{C})$.
Is this statement true for B(H)? if yes, how can i prove it?

Comment: Why it is easy to see for M_n? Can this easy reason be adapted/generalized?

Comment: for $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ we can use the property of trace map. i mean if there exist a linear multiplicative functional $\Phi$ on $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ then necessarily $\Phi(AB)=\Phi(BA)$ for every A and B in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$. So $\Phi$ is trace map. and we know that trace is not multiplicative. Thus there is no mutiplicative linear functional on $M_n(\mathbb{C})$. but how can prove it for B(H)?

Answer (score 6):

It is true for $B(H)$ also.  Another way to see it for $M_n$ when $n>1$ that may be extended in spirit to $B(H)$ is to note that $M_n$ is simple, and the kernel of a multiplicative linear functional would be an ideal of codimension $1$.  If $H$ is infinite dimensional then $B(H)$ is not simple, but it does have a unique maximal ideal, and the codimension is not $1$.  E.g., in the separable case the maximal ideal is the set $K(H)$ of compact operators on $H$, and the Calkin algebra $B(H)/K(H)$ is infinite dimensional.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a direct argument. Since $\Phi$ is onto and multiplicative, $\phi(I)=1$. Write $I=P+Q$ for two orthogonal equivalent projections. Then, as $PQ=0$, we have $\Phi(P)\Phi(Q)=0$, so at least one of them is zero. But as $P=V^*V$, $Q=VV^*$, we get $\Phi(P)=\Phi(Q)$, so both are zero. Then $1=\Phi(P+Q)=\Phi(P)+\Phi(Q)=0$, a contradiction.

Comment: Why is $P = V^*V$ and $Q = VV^*$ ?

Comment: It's the assumption: that $P,Q$ are equivalent. In $B(H)$, you can always do it.

Comment: Pretty elegant solution!